# Google Map API v3, Move map style in a separate file

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the API provided by Google map [v3] for a project. The map is heavily styled and I cannot figure out how to put the style section of my script in an external JavaScript file and call it within my function.

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
center: {lat:40, lng: -97.7313421},
zoom: 3,
clickable: true,
styles: [
        {
          "elementType": "geometry",
          "stylers": [
            {
              "color": "#212121"
            }
          ]
        }, ....
```

Just to be clear, I only want the style section of the array to be somewhere else.

Comment: Can you add a jsFiddle with your map code?

Comment: Unfortunately i can't give you my code because it contains my company's API key and the JSON file for the data loads only on our intranet but I duplicated the style on this one : [codepen](http://codepen.io/BastienAustin/pen/zoQvYp) . As you can dee the style is pretty long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Plunkr code put together.](http://plnkr.co/edit/q7I6n8NIsovjQ08YoTxZ?p=preview)

Place the raw style array into a single file (here `styles.js`) and use jQuery GET to pull that file in include that variable into your Google Map Style.

```js
...
function initMap() {
    var mapStyle = '';

    $.get( 'styles.js', function( data ) {
      if (data) {
        mapStyle = JSON.parse(data);
        map_options = {
          zoom: 10,
          center: {lat: 42.9456, lng: -122.2},
          styles: mapStyle
        }

        map_document = document.getElementById('map')
        map = new google.maps.Map(map_document,map_options);
        loadMarkers()
      }
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

Where the `styles.js` file contain the style exactly as you write it normally:

```
[
    {
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#212121"
            }
        ]
    },
 ...
 ]
```